# Do I need Windows 10 Pro to publish an ASP.NET Core web app to Azure?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-mvc, web-deployment

I created a free Azure account to host a MVC web app that I've been working on the last few months. The app uses Entity Framework and SQL Server LocalDB and everything works fine when hosted locally. To publish to Azure from Visual Studio, I followed this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-5.0#run-the-app) but received errors. I pasted some of the output below (particularly when things start to go wrong) but I trimmed a few things to shorten it:

```
Adding sitemanifest (sitemanifest).
Adding database 
Warning : Cannot connect to the database 'db'.  
Retrying operation 'Add' on object dbFullSql (data source=xxxx). Attempt 1 of 10.
"                                                                                "
Retrying operation 'Add' on object dbFullSql (data source=xxxx). Attempt 10 of 10.
Error : Web deployment task failed. 

(5/29/2021 11:41:08 AM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
The database 'db' could not be created.

Publish failed to deploy.
2>Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Looking in Azure, I can see the App Service, Resource Group, and SQL Database that were created during the publish process. To see if maybe it was a problem with my app, I created a new web app exactly like the tutorial says and tried publishing it, but I received the same errors even though the App Service, Resource Group, and SQL Database were processed on Azure's side just like what happened with my other app.

The MVC web apps use .NET 5.0 and I'm using Windows 10 Home along with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.10.0. Any feedback on what could be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: No, you definitely don't need Windows 10 pro (or windows at all). I don't know what's going wrong, but the os most probably is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No , ASP.Net core can run on Linux as well. You definitely don't need windows at all.
According to your error, it looks like there is no connectivity to database. Check if the connection has been established.

Comment: Any tips on how to check if the connection has been established?  The second app I created according to the tutorial includes this code in the Startup file:                                        
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));      AND                           appsettings.json uses the standard connection string: "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=db;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"

Comment: check connection string named DefaultConnection  in your app settings

Comment: I can see the database in SQL Object Explorer and the name of the db matches the db in the connection string. Are there any other ways to check the connection beyond that?

Comment: are you talking about the local instance or azure instance?

Comment: I'm talking about what I see in Visual Studio so the local instance. When publishing to Azure, do you know if I need to give the database the same name as what I see in appsettings.json?

Comment: That could be the issue, you cant connect from cloud to an on prem database, you need to enable the connectivity or create the database in azure and add the same connection string